# Count occurrences of joined column per row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table containing Courses.

```
create table Courses
(
  CourseId INTEGER
    primary key
  ...
);
```

Via a M2M linking table...

```
create table User_Course_Links
(
  UserId INTEGER not null
    references Users,
  CourseId INTEGER not null
    references Courses,
  unique (UserId, CourseId)
);
```

...I've connected it to a table containing Users.

```
create table Users
(
  UserId INTEGER
    primary key
  ...
);
```

Now I want to list all Courses and *how many Users* are connected to each. How can I do this?

```
+----------+-----------+
| CourseId | UserCount |
+----------+-----------+
| Course 1 |        20 |
| Course 2 |         5 |
| Course 3 |        12 |
| ...      |       ... |
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. One can use the following query:

```
SELECT Courses.CourseId, Count(Users.UserId) AS UserCount FROM Users
INNER JOIN User_Course_Links UCL on Users.UserId = UCL.UserId
INNER JOIN Courses Courses on UCL.CourseId = Courses.CourseId
GROUP BY Courses.CourseId
```

Which results in

```
+----------+-----------+
| CourseId | UserCount |
+----------+-----------+
| Course 1 |        20 |
| Course 2 |         5 |
| Course 3 |        12 |
| ...      |       ... |
```

Alternatively, one can use this query:

```
SELECT Courses.CourseId, Count(Users.UserId) AS UserCount FROM Courses
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Course_Links UCL on Courses.CourseId = UCL.CourseId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users on UCL.UserId = Users.UserId
GROUP BY Courses.CourseId
```

To also include the Courses with zero users